# To move column value to next row using sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query i am selecting the values from the table it has 4 columns name,age,class,rollno.And i want to display it in 2 columns (ie)to make 2 column value to move to next row and 4 column value to next row.Pls help me to do this.

```
StudentID|name/age|class/Roll no|
1          xxx       2
1           5        123556
2          yyy        2
2           5        123557

Select studentid,name.age,class,roll no from student
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION ALL` and use 2 queries. I had to cast the age as a varchar so that it could go in the name.age column

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27700/3)**

```
select id, name as 'name.age', class as 'class.rollno'
from student
union all
select id, cast(age as varchar), rollno
from student
order by id, name desc
```